# Javascript to Remove Elements loaded in iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, hide, html

After searching Google and Stack Overflow I decided to ask if this is even possible.

Currently I am loading an iFrame on my site. I wish to hide a certain element loaded in the iFrame.

```
<span id="blahblah">


function collapseAll(){

var body = document.getElementById('body');
var spans = body.getElementsByTagName("span");
var span;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
  span = spans[i];
  if(span.class=='blahblah'){
  span.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
 }
}
```

However this did not work. Question number one is can this be done? If yes could you explain how?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: This is done most easily using query strings in the iframe `src` attribute but can be accomplished cross-domain using JavaScript despite answers suggesting otherwise.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564466/how-to-hide-an-element-inside-html-iframe

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to put that script inside the contents of the iframe. You can't access the DOM of another frame, especially if it's from another domain.

Comment: Since it is an external site looks like I am out of luck then.

Comment: You contradict yourself by stating cross-domain is _especially_ not accessible which leads me to believe you feel your answer may be incorrect (which is it).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot access elements within an iframe from the outer window, due to security controls.

You would have to try this, but you might be able to create a function on the window object of the iframe and the call it from the outer window.

In the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.collapseAll = function() {
        .....
    }
</script>
```

In the outer window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doCollapse() {
        document.getElementById('my_iframe").window.collapseAll();
    }
</script>
```

Again, that's untested but I'm pretty sure Facebook does something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

if the iframe is from the same domain as your javascript is from then this is doable.

using plain javascript you would write the following

`

```
function collapseAll(){

var body = document.getElementById('body');
var spans = body.getElementsByTagName("span");
var span;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
  span = spans[i];
  if(span.class=='blahblah'){
  **span.style.display = "none";**
  }
 }
}
```

this fixes the issue.

if the iframe is from a different site (domain) then things would get really difficult..
there are solutions like greasemonkey which can operate on pages from different domains.

you can try

```
document.frame.document.getElementsByTagName('span')
```

Comment: Is there a way to use a greasemonkey like solution to load in this page (without the need for a greasemonkey plugin)?

Comment: don't think so.. the concept behind greasemonkey is not a default feature.. so the plugin is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function remove_elemment() {
    var body = document.getElementById('body');
 var divs = body.getElementsByTagName("div");
 var div;
 for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   div = divs[i];
   if(div.class=='buybox'){
    **div.style.display = "none";**
   }
 }
};

function doRemove() {
    document.frame.document.getElementById('my_iframe').remove_elemment();
}();

</script>
```

```html
<div class="floating-widget">
 <iframe id="my_iframe" src="http://www.nodebeginner.org/index-vi.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="500">    
 </iframe>

</div>
```